# certain character in url cause error 500

Tags: asp.net, redirect

After doing security scan on the website, these two characters **<a** can cause 500

http://domain.com/default.aspx?**<a**

The error is handled in Application_Error to redirect to the error.aspx page.

```
Application_Error()  
{  
 Response.Redirect("/error.aspx?asperrorpath=" + Context.Request.RawUrl);  
}
```

But the RawUrl does not appear as just value for the param asperrorpath, the Redirect will cause another 500, and infinite redirect loop happens.

The only solution that I got to avoid redirect loop is to encode the RawUrl, but we want to see the real URL that the user requested, encoding may cause some lost of information. Have any other solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this will serve your purpose.  Maybe you can replace them

```
Application_Error()  
{  
   Response.Redirect("/error.aspx?asperrorpath=" + String.Replace(Context.Request.RawUrl,"<a","^^$$^^");  
}
```

So if you see that pattern you can assume it is "< a"...  choose your combination so that it does not occur otherwise.

Comment: The problem, not only <a can cause the 500, there might be other possible character which I am not aware of. I guess the only way is to encode the whole RawUrl.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Context.Request.RawUrl);
```